# Wget images from directory

Tags: image, download, wget

Hey.
 I have a public directory that contains a number of JPG images. How can I use `WGET` in order to download each picture into a specific directory on my local machine? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wget -r --directory-prefix=/path/to/save/to -A jpg www.example.com/path/to/image/directory`

All from the [wget manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)

The `-A` argument allows you to specify the file name suffixes that you care about (there's also a similar `-R` to exclude files):

`-r` is recursive retrieval, so it will go into subdirectories.

`--directory-prefix=/path` specifies where to save to.

And the `-A` flag, I'll cut a snippet from the manual:

`-A acclist --accept acclist`

`-R rejlist --reject rejlist`

> Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to accept or reject (see Types of Files). Note that if any of the wildcard characters, ‘*’, ‘?’, ‘[’ or ‘]’, appear in an element of acclist or rejlist, it will be treated as a pattern, rather than a suffix.

Answer (score 0):

First of, ensure you have directory listing on your server (not a good setting imho).
Next, make wget get this listing, parse it somehow and finally wget each image.